# Ruby on Rails (3.2): every request tries to load /[timestamp]?_[timestamp]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

As the title says, every request in my Rails Production environment performs a request to the same page with ?_[timestamp] after it. It expects javascript, because that is what the headers say.

It seems this request slows down my page-loading, because every page now does two requests instead of one.

Does anybody know what is going on and whether it can be fixed?

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.2 with NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably in development mode ?! Then it is to prevent caching in the web browser. Change to production mode and it is gone if you want to run it on production.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but no. It is also the case in production. In development it is doing it twice even (with different timestamps)

Comment: Ignore the fact that it happens in development twice: this was because I had a public/assets precompiled version loaded. But it still loads in development and production once.

Comment: My bad, I was talking about the cache buster functionality with a random number to force a new load of the js file. The timestamp is on porpuse. This make sure you always load the correct file. So you checked with firebug and you get really 2 requests?

Comment: Tested it with the Safari inspector, but yes. The second one is a XHR which wants javascript, but because I don't have javascript for every page it returns the HTML. My guess is that it does this because it wants to know if this page is also available in JS, but I'm not sure why?